# java.util.TreeSet not following Set's no duplication contract?

Tags: java, collections, set, overriding, treeset

I have seen the problem being asked here before but I didn't get much help from then so I'm asking it again with my genuine problem.

I want to remove duplicate object on the basis of all properties of object (Here `Name, id, CompanyName, Address`). Here is My code:

```
package CollectionDemo;
import java.util.TreeSet;
class Employee implements Comparable<Employee> {
    String Name;
    int id;
    String CompanyName;
    String Address;
    public Employee(String Name,int id,String CompanyName,String Address) {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.id = id;
        this.CompanyName = CompanyName;
        this.Address = Address;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Name : "+this.Name+"\tID : "+this.id+"\tCompanyName : "+this.CompanyName+"\tAddress : "+this.Address;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Employee obj){
        if((this.Name.equals(obj.Name))&&(this.id==obj.id)&&(this.CompanyName.equals(obj.CompanyName))&&(this.Address.equals(obj.Address))) {
            return 0;
        }
        return 1;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class DemoTreeset {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeSet<Employee> ts = new TreeSet<>();
        ts.add(new Employee("Panda", 11, "Google", "California"));
        ts.add(new Employee("Panda", 12, "Google", "California"));
        ts.add(new Employee("Panda", 11, "Google", "California"));
        ts.add(new Employee("Panda", 13, "Google", "California"));
        ts.add(new Employee("Panda", 11, "Google", "California"));
        ts.add(new Employee("Panda", 11, "Infosys", "India"));
        ts.add(new Employee("Panda", 11, "Google", "California"));
        ts.add(new Employee("Panda", 11, "Infosys", "India"));
        ts.add(new Employee("Panda", 12, "Google", "California"));
        ts.add(new Employee("Panda", 11, "Google", "California"));
        ts.add(new Employee("Panda", 13, "Google", "California"));
        ts.add(new Employee("Panda", 11, "Google", "California"));
        ts.add(new Employee("Panda", 11, "Infosys", "India"));
        ts.add(new Employee("Panda", 11, "Google", "California"));
        ts.add(new Employee("Panda", 11, "Infosys", "India"));
        for(Employee  e : ts) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Name : Panda    ID : 11 CompanyName : Google    Address : California 
Name : Panda    ID : 12 CompanyName : Google    Address : California
Name : Panda    ID : 13 CompanyName : Google    Address : California
Name : Panda    ID : 11 CompanyName : Google    Address : California
Name : Panda    ID : 11 CompanyName : Infosys   Address : India
Name : Panda    ID : 13 CompanyName : Google    Address : California
```

I know `TreeSet` uses **`compareTo()`** instead of **`equals()`** to compare the objects so I override it but as you can see the output, **it removed some duplicates but not all of them**. I'm not understanding why I'm getting this output. Why is it not removing all the duplicates but only few of them?

Comment: How can anything (let alone `TreeSet`) use `equals()` to _compare the objects_?

Comment: @KedarMhaswade
I said TreeSet Uses compareTo() instead of equals() to compare the objects...

Comment: Short answer: your implementation of `compareTo` _massively_ violates the contract for that method, and `TreeSet` can't help you when you give it nonsensical implementations.

Comment: @MohammadNadeem I meant to ask if it is possible to compare two objects using the `equals()` method alone. I don't think it is possible. In other words, if you want to _compare_ objects you need a `compareTo()` implementation.

Comment: @KedarMhaswade
This is how i compare the objects by overriding the equals method and i usually dont implement compareTo()...


 public boolean equals(Object obj) {
  Student std = (Student)obj;
  if(this.Name.equalsIgnoreCase(std.Name)&&(this.rollno==std.rollno)&&this.College.equalsIgnoreCase(std.College)&&(this.Branch.equalsIgnoreCase(std.Branch))) {
   return true;
  }
  return false;
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you Check this one out?
Output:

> Name : Panda   ID : 11 CompanyName : Google    Address : California
>
> Name : Panda   ID : 12 CompanyName : Google    Address : California
>
> Name : Panda   ID : 13 CompanyName : Google    Address : California
>
> Name : Panda   ID : 11 CompanyName : Infosys   Address : India

```
package algorithms;

import java.util.TreeSet;

class Employee implements Comparable<Employee> {
String Name;
int id;
String CompanyName;
String Address;

public Employee(String Name,int id,String CompanyName,String Address) {
    this.Name = Name;
    this.id = id;
    this.CompanyName = CompanyName;
    this.Address = Address;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Name : "+this.Name+"\tID : "+this.id+"\tCompanyName : "+this.CompanyName+"\tAddress : "+this.Address;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Employee obj){
    final int BEFORE = -1;
    final int EQUAL = 0;
    final int AFTER = 1;

    if (this.equals(obj)) return EQUAL;
    
    int comparison = this.Name.compareTo(obj.Name);
    if (comparison != EQUAL) return comparison;

    comparison = this.Address.compareTo(obj.Address);
    if (comparison != EQUAL) return comparison;

    comparison = this.CompanyName.compareTo(obj.CompanyName);
    if (comparison != EQUAL) return comparison;

    comparison = ((Integer)(this.id)).compareTo(obj.id);
    if (comparison != EQUAL) return comparison;

    return EQUAL;
}

   @Override 
   public boolean equals(Object aThat) {
       if (this == aThat) return true;
       if (!(aThat instanceof Employee)) return false;

       Employee that = (Employee)aThat;
       return
           ( this.Address.equals(that.Address)) &&
           (this.id == that.id) &&
           ( this.Name.equals(that.Name) ) &&
           ( this.CompanyName.equals(that.CompanyName) )
         ;
   }
}


public class DemoTreeSet {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TreeSet<Employee> ts = new TreeSet<>();
    ts.add(new Employee("Panda", 11, "Google", "California"));
    ts.add(new Employee("Panda", 12, "Google", "California"));
    ts.add(new Employee("Panda", 11, "Google", "California"));
    ts.add(new Employee("Panda", 13, "Google", "California"));
    ts.add(new Employee("Panda", 11, "Google", "California"));
    ts.add(new Employee("Panda", 11, "Infosys", "India"));
    ts.add(new Employee("Panda", 11, "Google", "California"));
    ts.add(new Employee("Panda", 11, "Infosys", "India"));
    ts.add(new Employee("Panda", 12, "Google", "California"));
    ts.add(new Employee("Panda", 11, "Google", "California"));
    ts.add(new Employee("Panda", 13, "Google", "California"));
    ts.add(new Employee("Panda", 11, "Google", "California"));
    ts.add(new Employee("Panda", 11, "Infosys", "India"));
    ts.add(new Employee("Panda", 11, "Google", "California"));
    ts.add(new Employee("Panda", 11, "Infosys", "India"));
    for(Employee  e : ts) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: now the ans is perfect...thanks for the help sir...it helped a lot...:)

Answer (score 3):

When you implement the contract defined by the `Comparable` interface, you need to respect all aspects that the contract requires from an implementation. Partially respecting the contract will lead to strange behavior just as you experience in your case. One obvious omission from your implementation of the `Comparable` contract is **transitivity**. From the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-) of the `Comparable.compareTo(...)` method:

> The implementor must also ensure that the relation is transitive:
>   `(x.compareTo(y)>0 && y.compareTo(z)>0)` implies `x.compareTo(z)>0`.

Your implementation is definitely not transitive.

Comment: And specifically, you always return 1 ("this object is greater than the argument") if the two aren't equal. That means that "a" > "b" and "b" > "a" (since both would see the other as not equal, and thus return 1), which obviously doesn't hold.

Comment: @yshavit
m doing it becoz i just wanna check for duplicate objects...if obj is equal to arg return 0 else return 1 or -1...
what do i return if not 1 or -1?

Comment: Implement the `compareTo` method properly and it will work just fine. Create a **consistent** ordering and respect the `Comparable` contract and  everything will start working ;-)

Comment: @Nándor Előd Fekete
Sorry sir but u didnt get wat u are tryin to say...wat wud i do to make it work...can you plz show me correct way to do wat i want to do...

Comment: Returning -1 is fine, but your code never does it. :)

Comment: @yshavit
sir i ve tried tht too,by returning -1 instead of 1 just reverses the printing order nothing else...:(

Comment: No, it's not fine to return -1. You could define the ordering like this: order by name, id, companyName, address. That would mean, that if name differs, natural string ordering will decide the ordering of the `Employee` objects. If they are the same, you compare the ids. If they differ, they define ordering of `Employee` objects with the same name. If they are the same, you continue with the next property. This way, two `Employee` objects will only be the same if all the properties involved in your comparison will be the same.

Comment: Of course, if id is unique between unique employees, you can use only that for ordering.